# How does Set actually work internal when checking for values?

Tags: hash, set, big-o, notation

This is a very general computer science based question, but one that doesn't seem intuitive based on the literature about how they work.  It's a language agnostic question, but relates to how a Set data type works internally.

I have used them many times, and it is recommended to use them to store unique values and quickly access them.  Supposedly in Big-O notation its time and complexity is O(1) every time the Set is accessed.  How is that possibly if the Set may contain thousands of items?  Even if the items are unique.

In order to find an item in the Set, it still has to scan each and every unique item, which in Big-O is O(n) in time and complexity.  Is there anything I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance for your help!  Most thorough answer gets the up-vote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Set` is an example of a more general kind of objects collectively known as `HashedCollections`. These use some sort of `HashTable` to actually store and retrieve their elements.

Given any `element`, these tables compute an integer value for it named its `hash`. There are several well-known techniques to define the mapping between elements and their `hash` values. Some are *intrinsic*, in the sense that the `hash` does not depend on the attributes of the `element`, which might change, and hence the `hash` remains the same along the life of the `element`. Others are *extrinsic*, in the sense that they may depend on the attributes. However, in the latter case, it is supposed that the particular elements will not be modified while they are referenced from a `HashedCollection` (otherwise the `HashedCollection` must be `rehashed`).

The procedure for storing an `element` works as follows:

1. The `hash` is computed for the `element`.
2. An `index` to the table is computed as the remainder of the `hash` modulo the `length` of the table.
3. If the slot at the `index` so calculated is already taken, some policy is applied to resolve the *collision*.

Step 1 is supposed to be really fast (e.g., the `hash` has not `cryptographic` strength).

Step 2 assumes (in most of the cases) that the length of the table is a *prime* number (powers of `2` are also used)

Step 3 can be resolved in basically two different ways:

- The table is sequentially scanned `j` times until the slot at `index + j` is free, or
- The element is added to the collection of elements colliding at the given `index` (*bucket*)

In addition, if there aren't enough empty slots (which increases the probability of collision), the table is enlarged and `rehashed` (because the `modulo` changed).

With sufficient free slots and a fairly random distribution of the indexing mechanism, the probability of finding the desired slot in `O(1)` is very high. Of course, if too many elements collide, the average complexity is no longer `O(1)`, but this is supposedly mitigated by the growing policy (+ `rehash`).

The retrieval is similar. To check whether an `element` belongs in the collection, its `hash` and `modulo` are computed and the `element` is compared with the contents of the target slot. If the comparison fails, the search proceeds linearly in the bucket.

The removal of elements is somewhat more difficult when there is no `bucket` and instead the `indexes` are increased, but you get the idea.

If you really want to see all of this at work, go ahead and debug the basic operations of `HashedCollections` in any Smalltalk dialect. Lots of fun guaranteed.

Comment: Thank you so much for that very detailed and all inclusive answer Leandro!  I really appreciate you taking the time to write that up!  That was some great insight into what's going on under the hood.