# Why adding a collection to itself blows up in Smalltalk?

Tags: collections, smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I wonder why this is not terminating in GNU Smalltalk:

`s := Set new. s add: s`

In theory, `s` should be simply a set containing an empty set. But executing that just loops forever, blowing up the heap.

Interestingly,
`((s := Set with: 4 with: 5 with: 6) add: s) size.` terminates and evaluates to 4.

Comment: What dialect are you talking about? Pharo, Squeak, VA, VW, Smalltalk/X...

Comment: @MaxLeske I'm using GNU Smalltalk.

Comment: The expression `s := Set new. s add: s` is not a problem. What may cause a Stack Overflow (no pun intended) is printing `s`. Most dialects don't have this problem because they are careful when printing a collection.

Comment: @Leandro it could be a problem if adding a second time depending how hash is computed.

Comment: @aka.nice Good Catch! In fact, Pharo has this problem, namely `s := Set new. s add: s. s hash` crashes the VM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### An introduction

A `Set` is a kind of `HashedCollection` specifically designed for fast membership check. Internally a `Set` has a `HashTable`, a *sparce* array with many empty slots to minimize the number of *collisions*. When we `#add:` an element to the `Set`, an `index` to the `HashTable` is calculated as `(hash \\ size) + 1`, where `#\\` is the *mod* operation and `size` is the length of the table. If the slot at `index` is already occupied, the `index` is incremented until a free slot is found, and the element is stored there (*N.B.*, `+ 1` because Smalltalk arrays are `1`-based.) [cf. [How does Set actually work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55755896/4081336)]

### Our case

Now, let's see what happens with the code of the question:

```
1. s := Set new.
2. s add: s.
```

As described above, in step 2, `add: s` will compute:

```
s hash \\ p + 1
```

where `p` is the initial number of slots of `s`'s inner table (a prime number, set to `5` or `7` when the set is first created, and increased later as needed.)

So far, so good. But there might be some

### Issues

Where? Depending on the Smalltalk dialect, there might be an issue with `#printOn:` or with the next `add:`ition of an element.

**The printing issue**

A problem that might happen with `#printOn:` is *infinite recursion*. When printing `s`, one would want to print its elements as well, and in our case such an approach would recursively try to print `s` in the process, creating an endless circularity.

To prevent this from happening, `Pharo` uses a `LimitedWriteStream` that will stop writing after a certain number of iterations, breaking the recursion, should it exist.

I haven't checked it myself, but this is the issue that seems to be happening in GNU Smalltalk (according to the question.)

Note that it is not enough to print only a max number of elements in the `Set`. In fact, our set only contains one element (itself), which is enough to create the recursion.

**The addition issue**

As observed by @aka.nice in his comment, care must also be taken when adding `s` a second time. Why? Because, as we have seen in the introduction above, the message `add: s` will need to compute `s hash …`. And how is `s hash` defined? This is an interesting question. Smalltalkers are routinely confronted with the problem of implementing a good `#hash` in some classes. Since `s` is a collection, it is tempting to take the `hash` of its elements into account for the final result, right? Pharo takes this approach, look:

```
hash
  | hash |
  hash := self species hash.
  self size <= 10 ifTrue:
    [self do: [:elem | hash := hash bitXor: elem hash]].
  ^hash bitXor: self size hash
```

which *swallows the bait*. Why? Because the set `s` has 1 element (itself), so the condition `self size <= 10` is `true`, and the method will try to recursively compute `s hash` again, leading to, oh oh, *Stack Overflow*.

### Conclusions

1. Be careful when implementing `Collection >> #printOn:`. Even if the collection doesn't contain itself, a recursion might arise if there is an indirect reference from one of the elements back to the collection containing it.
2. Be careful when implementing `Collection >> #hash` (same reasons)
3. Be careful when adding a `Collection` to itself. More generally, be careful when a collection contains an element with a (possibly indirect) reference to it, because enumerating such a collection may be tricky.
4. In Mathematics (the Science), a *Set* cannot be an element of itself (this is explicitly forbidden by the Axioms of Set Theory). So, re-think your model before violating this rule that comes from an extremely mature and evolved scientific body of knowledge.

Comment: nice answer and I really like the note ad 4).